# AFNetworking: Prevent Redirect

Tags: redirect, afnetworking

I am currently using AFNetworking to send off HTTP requests. The server is currently set up to respond with a redirect to another HTML page in both a fail and success scenario (Our client has control over the server and we cannot change its behavior without a lot of bureaucracy).

I need to catch when it redirects to the success HTML page and not automatically post another HTTP request afterwords due to the redirect.

```
- (void) fetchHttpRequest: (void (^)(id result)) completionBlock
               errorBlock: (void (^)(NSError * error, id result)) errorBlock
{
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                    [NSURL URLWithString:@"/"]];// replace with correct url

AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                                      initWithRequest:urlRequest];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, id result)
 {
     completionBlock(result);
 }
                                 failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, NSError *error)
 {
     errorBlock(error, nil);
 }];
// check the redirection
[operation setRedirectResponseBlock:
 ^NSURLRequest *(NSURLConnection *connection, NSURLRequest *request,
                 NSURLResponse *redirectResponse)
 {
     NSString * reqUrlPath = @"/";// replace with success URL
     if ([reqUrlPath isEqualToString:[[request URL] path]])
     {
         // success case
         return nil;
     }
     else
     {
         // failure case
         return request;
     }
 }];
[operation start];
}
```

The completion block on the operation does not catch any successes until the app has already been redirected, which results in a failure.

It does reach the `// success case` in the redirect block, but I cannot stop the code from attempting to go to the next page at that location due to the required return type. Thus, where I define the `completionBlock`, it receives an error instead of a completion.